# How to set background image for Angular component?

Tags: css, angular, url, background-image

In my angular app I would like to set a background image for a specific view.

To this end, I added the following to the css-file of a component:

```
body {
       background-image: url("../../../assets/images/backgroundImage.jpg");
   }
```

However, the background doesn't change.

This the the file path of the file containing the css-code shown above:

angular-app/src/app/users/profile/profile.component.css

... and this is the file path of the background-image:

angular-app/src/assets/images/backgroundImage.jpg

---

I also tried

```
body {
       background-image: url("assets/images/backgroundImage.jpg");
   }
```

... but this resulted in a warning during compilation and didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I gave the root element class "root" and then put the following into the css-file:

```
.root {
   background-image: url("../../../assets/images/backgroundImage.jpg");
}
```

... now the background changes but not for the whole vertical length of the screen (the lower part remains white):

[image]

Comment: If you want it to apply to the body tag, put it in `styles.css`

Comment: but then it would be applied to all components/views, wouldn't it? ... I want it to be applied to only this specific view

Comment: Then you need to apply it to the root tag of that component, i.e. if the first line in your HTML file is `<div id="test" />` then you should apply it to `#test`. When Angular builds the application, it applies something called ViewEncapsulation, so the CSS in your component CSS file will (usually) only apply to the HTML in that particular component

Comment: That you ... now the background is visible ... but only for parts of the screen (see update to my post)

Comment: for not filling whole screen add this
`html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}`

Comment: @Obed thank you for your suggestion ... I had already added this anyway ... but it doesn't make the image cover the whole screen

Comment: If you also add `position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0` to the CSS rule, it will take up the whole screen

Answer (score 5):

According to [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-scope), The styles specified in `@Component` metadata apply only within the template of that component.

you can use a hack like this

In your `styless.css` file add this

```
.selector {
       background-image: url("../../../assets/images/backgroundImage.jpg");
   }
```

now in your component you can do this

```
ngOnInit() {
    document.body.className = "selector";
  }

ngOnDestroy(){
    document.body.className="";
  }
```

But this is highly not recommended, i dont know what your code looks like, but there must be another way.

1. Scale your component to fit whole view-port
2. set the background on your component

I will work on a plunker and link to this file as an edit when done

Comment: thank you fro your answer ... unfortunately, the url can't be resolved any more when I put the .selector into the styles.css file ... (I also tried using 'background-image: url("./assets/images/backgroundImage.jpg");' but that didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

I will add another answer for this because its totaly different from my previous answer

in your component import `ViewEncapsulation` from `angular/core`

```
import { ..., ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
```

In your @component metatag add   `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,`

```
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  ...
})
```

This has a side effect though, all styles in your component will be available to all other components once it loads.

You can check more about it on the [Angular](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) page

Comment: this makes the background-image disappear completely (except for small socket at the bottom of the screen)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to either create a service or use ngrx to communicate between the child component and app.component to switch the style of the app.component.html using ngClass.

Answer (score 0):

This Works for me,

```
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background', 'url("../../../assets/images/form-bg.png")');
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background-size', 'cover');
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background-attachment', 'fixed');
  }
```

Comment: **nop** the url is not related your tree of directories, You always need think that in product you have: index.html, styles.css and assets folder in a "root". Generally work `./assets`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem in my Component. I solved this by putting the css code down in styles.css
i div taged the whole body

```
.background-IMG {
  background-image: url(../src/app/components/login/images/bg.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```